# Error with a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, sprite-kit

I'm making a game in SpriteKit and I wrote this to make a moving background:

```
        let spaceMovement = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx:0, dy:-bg1.frame.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(0.4 * bg1.frame.size.height))
        let resetSpace = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx:0, dy:bg1.frame.size.height), duration: 0.0)
        let repeatSpaceMovement = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([spaceMovement, resetSpace]))

        for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < self.frame.size.height / (bg1.size.height); i++
        {
            let sprite = self.bg1;
            sprite.zPosition = -20
            sprite.position = CGPointMake(sprite.size.width/2, i * sprite.size.height)
            sprite.runAction(repeatSpaceMovement)
            self.addChild(sprite)

        }
```

but it gave me this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Which line exactly and what is the complete error?

Comment: @rmaddy I put a breakpoint and it happens in this line `for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < self.frame.size.height / (bg1.size.height); i++` . It also says that C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift.

Comment: Could tell us what's the value of `bg1.size.height`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a .frame, so you end up dividing by 0? Maybe you meant:

```
for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < self.frame.size.height / (bg1.frame.size.height); i++
```

Also, don't use C++ style loops.  They are going away and they are ugly.  How about this?  It should behave identically.

```
for i in (0..<self.frame.size.height / bg1.frame.size.height) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you check the value of bg1.frame.size.height?

Comment: I used that for statement and it says: "Use of an unresolved operator '..' "

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `...`

Comment: I don't think that `..<` or `...` operator will work with `CGFloat`. Probably it would be better to round the upper limit to an integer first.